# Отключение всех соединений в пуле

Tags: java, база-данных, servlet, jdbc

Использую com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource, установлено максимальное количество соединений - 60. Изначально было меньше, но увеличение не помогает решению проблемы. Все параметры указаны, но когда количество соединений резко доходит до 60, к примеру за одну минуту, после этого они остаются занятыми и не освобождаются, новые также не создаются. Вопрос в том, как можно сделать так, чтобы, если достигнуто 60 соединений, он хотя бы закрывал те соединения, которым уже 30 секунд. Я использую

```
if(cpds.getNumUnclosedOrphanedConnections() == 59){
    cpds.softResetAllUsers();
}
```

но он слишком жестко работает, закрывает все соединения

```
ComboPooledDataSource  cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass(driverClassName);          // Класс драйвера базы
cpds.setJdbcUrl(url);                          // JDBC - урл
cpds.setUser(username);                        // Пользователь
cpds.setPassword(password);                    // Пароль
cpds.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);              // Максимальный размер пула

cpds.setInitialPoolSize(3);                    // Размер пула при инициализации
cpds.setMinPoolSize(3);                        // Минимальный размер пула

cpds.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");        // Запрос для теста соединения
cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);          // Период проверки ожидающих соединений (сек.)
cpds.setMaxIdleTime(20 * 60);                  // Таймаут ожидающего соединения (сек.)
cpds.setUnreturnedConnectionTimeout(5 * 60);   // Таймаут соединения, которое не было возвращено в пул (сек.)
cpds.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(30 * 60); // Промежуток времени в течение которого проверяется пул,
// и сокращается кол-во соединений в нем в случае неиспользования их (сек.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Хотел блин поковыряться в неизвестном языке.. но тут без описания кто к чему :)) но много методов Get с различными вариантами статусов пользователей т.е. соединений :) 
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html

Там можно получить их номера и сделать softReset(по пользователю)

Comment: У меня только один пользователь, и все соединения использует только он один, могу хранить айди все открытых сессий, connection.getMetaData() он возвращает айди сеодинения, можно ли как то по нему делать поиск соединения и закрывать  по нему.

Comment: Зачем одному пользователю столько соединений? Может быть проблема в том, что соединения некорректно возвращаются в пул?

Comment: @a_gura используется только один пользователь на сайте, все соединения идут с ним, вообще для него даже 10 много, но иногда по пока не понятным причинам этих соединения мгновенно доходит до максимума.

Comment: @YeldosTanikin Это все ясно из самого вопроса. В общем вам не нужен ответ на ваш вопрос, вам нужно понять, почему резко растет кол-во занятых соединений.

Comment: @a-gura ну если бы я мог понять почему так резко возрастает, что пытаемся понять уже долгое время,  я бы сюда не обращался.